# Color is not applied when drawing fonts in BGE with blf and bgl

Tags: game-engine, opengl

I am trying to get fonts rendered with different colors, but bgl.glColor4f (or any other variant of glColor) doesn't apply the color that I set with it. Please see https://github.com/eugenschindler/blender-examples/tree/master/HUDText for a reproduction of the problem (Blend file, Python script, and font).
According to other resources I found online, this example code should work, but I can't get it to work.
I've used Blender 2.73 and 2.75 and in both it doesn't work.
Does anybody have an idea what's going wrong?

Comment: I tried to open your .blend, nothing was there. Can you re-upload it on something else?

Comment: You have to switch to blender game engine and then press p to play it, then you'll see the text.

Comment: Oh, well now that you fixed it all i can say is you should vote your answer as the working answer.

Comment: It says that you can't vote for your own post. I guess I have to wait some time.

Comment: Odd, i've seen people vote their own before. Another one of them permission things again i guess.

Comment: I was able to click "accept" instead of vote, but only after a few days.

Comment: Oh good, good to know as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was lying in the Shading settings of Blender. By default, the shading is set to Multitexture, which makes the blf text be only black. If you set the shader to GLSL (see picture below), the colors behave exactly as you would expect them according to the python script that is in my example.

[image: Blender Shader settings]